# Redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com on Apache

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to redirect http://example.com to https://www.example.com on Apache

Using: https://varvy.com/tools/redirects/ with my domain https://www.a-c-d.net

I have two redirects in `no www`.

In my .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.a-c-d.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

In https://varvy.com/tools/redirects/ I want to have 1 redirect in `www`,  `no www`,  `no www(https)` and 0 redirects in `www(https)`.

Thanks

Ben